# How to get form POST data with Firebug?

Tags: php, variables, post, firebug

I need, in my debugging phase, to lookup what passes in the `$_POST` variable in a page that I can't currently touch (it's live online.)

I picked up my trusty Firebug, and can't find an option making it able to read this PHP variable.

So how could I checkup what is in that `$_POST` variable, without touching the code of the page I'm viewing?

Comment: you can't read server side stuff without some work.

Comment: @DanielA.White: It's not necessarily server side stuff since your browser sent the POST data. So, unless your server or browser are buggy, it should be the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice alternative: [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/tamper-data-for-ff-quantum/)

You can even modify post data before submitting.

2019-06-20: link updated

Comment: I would gladly tryout that answer, but it seems that Firefox plugins is down... can't download anything from it.

Comment: @sascha, The 'TamperData' link is not valid now. It would be great if you can update it

Answer (score 17):

Check this answer [Use Net Tab of Firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350779/to-see-the-content-post-data-trasferred-by-jquery#answer-1350793).  There is POST info in that tab too!

Original question:[To see the content POST data trasferred by jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350779/to-see-the-content-post-data-trasferred-by-jquery)